# trigger blur() function using dojo (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, dojo

Anyone know how to trigger a `.blur()` event using dojo `v1.6`?

I have some code that `connects` the blur function, and it works when i manually click and blur the input:

`dojo.connect(dojo.byId('email'), "onblur", this, checkEmail);`

however this does not trigger the blur:

`dojo.byId('email').blur()`

Anyone have any ideas? I see some answers here, but they all relate to v1.7+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dojo does not provide any function for dispatching the blur event, however you can trigger it manually. Here is a function you can use that takes a reference to an element node as a paramter:

```js
function blur(el){
    if(el.fireEvent) // IE
        el.fireEvent("onblur");
    else {
        var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        evt.initEvent("blur", false, true);
        el.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
};
```